# PR shows "There are no changes" even when there are changes that have been pushed

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-merge, pull-request

I have an unstable `master`. I am working on correcting it.

The last stable state of `master` is at commit ID SHA1 and all the commits are faulty thereafter and therefore I wish to do away with them. Since there are a lot of commits, instead of reverting I took a branch from `SHA1` and made my changes on that branch with commit IDs `SHA2`, `SHA3` and `SHA4`. When I raise a PR for merging my branch into master I see the message in the DIFF as "`There are no changes`" .

[image: No changes]

whereas when I am comparing my branch to the master the changes are visible in the Diff.

[image: changes visible on comparing the branch with master]

**Why is this happening ?**